# Sources citing MSE

Tags: discussion, citation

Let's keep track of places that cite MSE.

For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group#cite_note-metabelian-2 and mathworld from the batman thread do.

Comment: Google yields a few more Wikipedia articles: ["math.stackexchange.com" site:wikipedia.org](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22math.stackexchange.com%22+site:wikipedia.org)

Comment: Ack, considering how frequently MSE answers cite Wikipedia, I find it disturbing that Wikipedia now cites back to MSE, potentially violating the [axiom of regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity)...

Comment: Maybe we should have another thread to keep track of circular references to/from m.se.

Comment: Wikipedia also has a possibility to search for links to specific site [using insource:"math.stackexchange.com"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?sort=relevance&search=insource%3A%22math.stackexchange.com%22&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&advancedSearch-current=%7B%7D&ns0=1&ns1=1).